# How to multiply values in colums using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to multiply the values in one column in SQL2012 by a fixed number and insert them in another column. For example here is a table and I want to multiply the age by 2 and insert in age2 column.

```
id    name      age age2
1     Person1   14  14
2     Person2   16  16
3     Person3   18  18
4     Person4   22  22
5     Person5   15  15
6     Person6   18  18
```

Comment: `SELECT id, name, age, age*2 as age2....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE YOURTABLENAME
SET age2 = age * 2
```

OR IF age2 doesn't exist you can do it in a select:

```
SELECT id, name, age, age * 2 as age2
FROM YOURTABLENAME
```

Comment: I already had the age2 column but I used your second option because I wanted to use some operators on the names and it worked! thanks

Comment: How do I? UPDATE and use where name != 'Person2'

Comment: I figured it out, I need more or less coffee... or something

Answer (score 1):

You don't insert data into columns, you insert rows. You would use an update:

```
update
  TheTable
set
  age2 = age * 2
```